# Every component from the solution of $\dot X = AX, X(t_o)=X_0$ is a non decreasing function in I=[$t_0,oo$]

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let A $\in$ R be a matriz whose elements are non negative. Let $X_0 \in $ R
.

Then every component from the solution of $\dot X = AX, X(t_o)=X_0$ is a non decreasing function in I=[$t_0,oo$]

I would like to know if this is really truth, because I am not sure. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, i meant decreasing.

Comment: @geetha290krm : That would be true for the solution to $\dot X=XA$. Matrices in general are not commutative, order matters.

Comment: The solution is $X(t)=e^{(t-t_0)A} X_0$. Thanks to @LutzLehmann for the correction.